# how to draw semicircle using 'path' element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to use the `path` element to create a semi circle, I've consulted the Bezier's curve but it seems do not work.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Here you go [Drawing semicircle using path](https://codepen.io/techniq/pen/RRxBxB)

Comment: Use the A command. `<path d="M25,75A50,50 0 0 1 125,75" />` Do you need it drawn with Bézier?

Comment: If you need to draw the semicircle with Bézier curves you may like to read this article: [Drawing a circle with Bézier Curves](http://whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/)

Comment: I forgot the `arc` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double factor = 0.75;
Path path = new Path();
path.lineTo(size.width * factor, 0);
path.cubicTo(size.width*factor, 0, size.width*factor + size.height, size.height/2 , size.width*factor, size.height);
path.lineTo(size.width*factor, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
return path;
```

ps. this is in flutter, but can be used with anything else

this should be almost answer.
Here im trying to round a container, in one end, to get it like a test tube